# Changing countif range automatically

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula to count the word red in the last 30 days but the range is not changing when a new row is added at the bottom.

How can I change the formula so when a new row is added at the bottom the range is adjusted automatically? The quantity of rows to check is always 30.

```
=COUNTIF(D2433:D2463, "Red")
```

Comment: 1) are there any blank rows in your data? ie, header row, followed by a blank spacer row, then your data? 2) are all the cells below the last entry all the way to row 1048576 empty? 3) does your data start in row 2433 or is that just an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$2433,0,0,30,1),"Red")
```

The references you are using $D$2433 till $D$2463 count 31 if you need 31 change in the above formula 30 to 31
Offset will start in $D$2433 and count the rows down in the same column
Countif will count if Red

**Update**
If in column D you insert only Data to be counted, you can use :

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT("$D$"&MAX(IF($D:$D<>"",ROW($D:$D),0))),0,0,-30,1),"Red")
```

This is an array formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>
The new formula will find the last non empty row in column D and Indirect will correct the formula automatically

Comment: @ian0411 - Your formula counts all instances of Red in COL D, I need to count only the instances of Red in the last 30 COL. And I also need the formula change the range as soon as a new row is added at the bottom. For example, when row D2464 is added, the formula change to include row D2464 within the 30 rows range. Thank you.

Comment: @yass- That won't work as needed. I need the formula change to 2434 when a new row is added at the bottom so it keeps counting only the last 30 rows. Thanks.

Comment: I have tested all formulas and found that only the one from yass worked, still with a little modification. I have defined the 30 days as negative number (-30) and changed the range to $D$2463.

Comment: @Camberra CacaitA I have updated the formula to change automatically when you add a new row at the end

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is using a **dynamic named range**:

1. `Formula > Name Manager > New`: Give a Name first and then insert the following formula into `Referes to` field.  Also see the picture.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,1):INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,INDEX(MAX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet1!A:A))),0))`

This should give you a range like `$A$1:$A$300` depends where the last non-empty cell is.

2. Now in the cell that you want to evaluate, add this formula:

`=COUNTIF(rng,"red")`

Please note `rng` is the named range that you should change to the name you want to use.

This will find the last cell and even work for blank cells.  Try and let me know if you have any question.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure where you range would be (a column, a row, or an area) but you can always change that Sheet1!A:A in the formula to just include the area that you will want to cover. But it only works for one column or let me know and I can update the formula for you. Also, you may want to rethink the design if someone has to scroll down to row 2433 to find the answer.

Comment: @CamberraCacaitA, okay, I am confused.  Do you mean my method won't work or the method that Forward Ed provided?  I have tested the code and it worked as expected.  It also takes care of any blank cells in the column.  But let me know if I am missing any criteria that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a relative cell reference. You can do this with the

```
=OFFSET()
```

function.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(D:D)/--((D:D)<>""),1)-30):INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(D:D)/--((D:D)<>""),1)),"Red")
```

Conditions:

There all rows beneath the last row must be blank
There cannot be any blank row within the last 30 row or your count may be off.

This is an array like function.  If you use full range references it checks 1048576 cells each time the aggregate function references the full column range.  As such if you use the formula a lot you can bog down your computer,  if you are only using it a couple of time you will probably be ok.